# The limit of Int32 for Identity Column

Tags: design, .net, performance, database-design

This is just a consideration for a site am creating and for other big sites out there.

I am using Identity Column to store the ID of some of my tables and I have classes whose Id are decorated with `Int32` to hold the value of the ID retrieved from database.

My worry is that as the site grows bigger, some tables that grows exponentially e.g `QuestionComments` might exceed the `Int32` limit in future. So I change my class to use `long`.

```
public class Question
{
   public long QuestionID { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

//Converting database value to .Net type

```
 Question q = new Question();
 q.QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(myDataRow["QuestionID"]);
```

How true is my assumption? Would using a UniqueIdentifier be better? Are there other way to address this?

**UPDATE:**

But for the sake of learning, how would site like FaceBook, Google, StackOverflow etc. handle Visit table assuming they have VisitID as Identity Column

Comment: what field are you using to store the data in the database? use the one that most closely matches it. do you really think 2 billion is a small enough number to cause issues? for instance, this site has been going for years and features only 20k questions. SO has only ~3.5 million.

Comment: now I know better. I underestimated that value (Int32). If I go by YAGNI, then this question is already answered. But for the sake of learning, how would site like FaceBook, Google, StackOverflow etc. handle `Visit` table assuming they have VisitID as Identity Column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Int32` is a 32 bit integer. It's also signed. This means it can hold 2^<sup>31</sup> - 1  different positive values. This comes to:

> 2,147,483,647

That's over 2 **billion** unique IDs. If you can use an unsigned integer this doubles to 4 billion.

`long` is a 64 bit signed integer. That's 2^<sup>63</sup> - 1 different positive values which comes to:

> 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

That's over 9 **quintillion** unique IDs (name courtesy of http://www.webmath.com) which is many orders of magnitude more than the 32 bit integer can hold.

So if you think you are going to get over 2 billion entities in any of your tables you should use `long`. This *should* be enough for any purpose.

Comment: now I know better. I underestimated that value (Int32). Billion is not a small number

Comment: If I may add too, 2 billions is not that big, and if ever you reach this number, this will be nasty. My personal choice is always to use 64 bits int for identity. That's not an effort, this is just a choice to make. That doesn't make your life worse and you fell better!

Comment: If I may add, make sure that the types you use in your code maps exactly to the data types on your table definition please see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I was under the impression that any modern database used a 64-bit unsigned "long" integer as a surrogate key (unique identifier) by default.  In MySQL, every record has a row number and if you declare this column properly, it does not actually take any (additional) storage in the database.  Why would you ever use anything else?

Comment: on a 64-bit server this is true, on a 32-bit one however, you're doing a lot more processing of those 64-bit numbers.

Comment: Can you provide links to some examples?  Also, how big of a processing hit are we talking about?  I don't think any math is being performed with unique IDs.  64-bit keys on a 32-bit system would take 2 retrievals and 2 comparisons instead of 1.  But it's still probably a lot faster than using strings, especially if character encoding is involved.  Hey, if 32-bits is enough, then that's great!